# Anti-derivative question with initial value 

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The solution of the initial value problem:

$$dy/dx = -9x^2$$

$$y(0) = 4$$

what is $y$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dy=-9x^2 dx \Rightarrow y=-9\cdot\int x^2 \,dx \Rightarrow y=-9 \cdot \frac{x^3}{3} +C \Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow y=-3x^3+C \Rightarrow 4=-3 \cdot 0 +C \Rightarrow C=4 \Rightarrow$

$y=-3\cdot x^3+4$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

The derivative of $y$ is $-9x^2$. The antiderivative of $-9x^2$ is therefore ...

The antiderivative of $-9x^2$ will include an additive constant $C$.  Use the initial condition $y(0)=4$ to find the value of $C$.